# Is recursive bind mounting possible in Linux, preferrably without extra tools?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

Here is a test with both `mount --bind` and `mount --rbind` options, neither of which goes full-recursion:

```
$ tree
.
├── adir
│   ├── afile
│   └── bbind
└── bdir
    ├── abind
    └── bfile

$ sudo mount --bind adir bdir/abind
$ sudo mount --bind bdir adir/bbind
$ tree
.
├── adir
│   ├── afile
│   └── bbind
│       ├── abind
│       └── bfile
└── bdir
    ├── abind
    │   ├── afile
    │   └── bbind
    │       ├── abind
    │       └── bfile
    └── bfile

# unmount the above, then:
    
$ sudo mount --rbind bdir adir/bbind
$ sudo mount --rbind adir bdir/abind
$ tree
.
├── adir
│   ├── afile
│   └── bbind
│       ├── abind
│       │   ├── afile
│       │   └── bbind
│       │       ├── abind
│       │       └── bfile
│       └── bfile
└── bdir
    ├── abind
    │   ├── afile
    │   └── bbind
    │       ├── abind
    │       └── bfile
    └── bfile
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730589/create-a-loop-in-a-linux-filesystem